This error handler cannot process 'org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException's; no record information is available
When Migrating my Java from Spring 2.x to 3.x, I upgraded my spring-kafka dependency too, to version 3.0.13. Now that deprecated the old Error Handler I was using that was, SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler.
This is what I am using now:
factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(2000, 5)));
But now I started getting this error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException's; no record information is available
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler.handleOtherException(DefaultErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1961)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1396)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Unexpected error from SyncGroup: The server experienced an unexpected error when processing the request.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$SyncGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:852)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$SyncGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:771)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:1260)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:1235)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:206)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:169)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:129)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.fireCompletion(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:617)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.firePendingCompletedRequests(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:427)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:312)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:251)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1307)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1243)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1216)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1676)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1651)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1344)
    ... 2 more


Dependency:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.13</version>
        </dependency>

Thanks in advance.
Expecting the new error handler to have the same business logic as SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler

This error was resolved. I actually was providing wrong bootstrap address which wasnt visible in the log file. So I tweaked the DefaultErrorHandler a little and now it works. It is just a matter of visibility of errors if you use a log file instead of consoleLogger.
public class CustomSeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler extends DefaultErrorHandler {
private static final Logger ALERT_LOG                     = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(LoggerConstant.ALERT_LOG);

@Override
public void handleOtherException(Exception thrownException, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container, boolean batchListener) {
    ALERT_LOG.error("Kafka Exception", thrownException);
}

}
